# C# can't have two properties with the same name?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm converting code from VB.net to C# and I've run into a minor issue. There's a number of places where we have private arrays that we expose through two properties, one that gets and sets the array as a whole, and another that returns a single item. Here's an example in the original...

```
Private pAmount as Double()
Friend Property Amount As Double()
    Get
        Return pAmount
    End Get
    Set(value As Double())
        pAmount = value
    End Set
End Property
Friend Property Amount(ByVal idx As Integer) As Double
    Get
        If idx < 0 OrElse idx >= pAmount.Length Then Return 0.0
        Return pAmount(idx)
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If idx < 0 OrElse idx >= pAmount.Length Then Return
        pAmount(idx) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I've tried this...

```
    private double[] pAmount;
internal double[] Amount {
    get { return pAmount; }
    set { pAmount = value; }
}
internal double Amount(int idx) {
    get {
        if (idx < 0 || idx >= pAmount.Length) return 0.0;
        return pAmount[idx];
    }
    set {
        if (idx < 0 || idx >= pAmount.Length) return 0.0;
        pAmount[idx] = value;
    }
}
```

But this does not work, it does not allow the second `Amount`. It seems they should, as both the inputs and outputs are different. Am I missing something else here that makes this invalid? Perhaps since it's an accessor into an array I need different syntax? Somewhere else in the code I get a message about a "method group", but I'm not sure I understand that.

Comment: That would probably work better as a collection class.

Comment: @Plutonix do you mean the underlying double[], or the entire containing class? Since the "method" is really part of the collection it would see that I should put it there, maybe a `InfiniteBoundsDoubleArray` or something, but won't that have lots of downstream API changes? Or is this something where interfaces help - I'm still not totally groking this.

Answer (score 3):

C# can't do that. VB.NET indexer properties are more expressive.

C# gives you a single indexer name. You can apply an attribute to rename all indexers but they can't have different names (I just tried that). This is really arcane stuff. I have never seen it being done. I only read about it once like 10 years ago.

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("TheItem")]
public int this [int index]   // Indexer declaration
{
}
```

This renames the indexer... But that helps you nothing.

That's not the way it's supposed to be done in general. It's against API guidelines to use indexers like that (I'd normally call it "abuse").

Why is your array property called `Amount`? It should be called `Amount**s**` and the naming conflict goes away.

You also can use methods to port this code. They can be overloaded.

Comment: Indeed, but then it conflicts with another method, `Amounts()`. Can you explain the "indexer properties are more expressive" part? Maybe I don't have to do any of this and there's something in the language itself?

Comment: C# gives you a singe indexer with one parameter. That's all. You can apply an attribute to rename that indexer. This is really arcane stuff. I have never seen it being done. I only read about it once like 10 years ago.

Comment: `Amounts()` is a bad name for a method, since it is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @RaymondChen hey Raymond, I didn't know that you roam the .net tags?! Normally Win32 is your domain. Preparing for 2016 .NET week?

Comment: @usr "_C# gives you a singe indexer with one parameter_" I would say the indexer can have many parameters, e. g. `public int this[int a, int b, string s] { ... }`. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have confused things. I have read over the MS page on indexers and either I understand it wrong, or this doesn't seem to apply. These properties are not properties of the class, they simply return a hidden internal value. The class is not a collection class, and is not called Amounts.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz indexers are properties at the assembly metadata level. They are properties with arguments. The VB code that you have shown seems to declare what C# calls indexers. Do you agree?

Comment: Perhaps... under c# are *all* properties with arguments automatically considered indexers? If so, then it appears yes, which means I'm screwed according to the post below.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz you are screwed, yes :) In order to declare a parameterized property you must use the special indexer syntax (see the code snippet).

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz if you want advice on what to do, write methods. You have all the flexibility you want with them.

Comment: Except the flexibility to do `Amount(1) = 5.0`! Curiously, VBA uses this exact syntax, and I know much of it is in c# - consider Worksheets vs. Worksheets(1).

Comment: There must be something I can do here. VB supports this so it's not a runtime issue, and this array is only one of several in that object. There must be some way to expose multiple arrays in a C# class, no?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You can expose arrays as normal properties. Just not parameterized ones. Maybe you should create a custom collection class and expose an instance of that as a properties. That's how 99% of the BCL does it. That allows you to write x.Amounts as well as x.Amounts[1] as well as x.Amounts[1] = 2. A custom collection allows you to hook in arbitrary logic into the getter and setter which an array cannot do. Look at how, for example, WinForms Control.Controls does it.

Comment: @usr, this sounds like the way to go. Do you have a complete example that you can point me to? It seems my google-fu is once again failing me.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz hm, https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=c%23+custom+collection looks good. Try not to over-engineer this. Choose the minimal design that will work.

Comment: I guess I'll just go with methods and let the API stink (use `[]` for some accessors, `()` for others you get to guess which one!). Otherwise I need to declare about 75 new classes, all with a single method in them, all on base objects like double. I'll chalk this up to another MS left-hand-right-hand issue.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz you can create one class that has all the common behavior. Then, you inject special behaviors using delegates into that class. That should be reasonably convenient. You can use generics for the element type. That API would stink less.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible according to C# 5 specification (section 10.3):

> • The name of a constant, field, property, event, or type must differ
>   from the names of all other members declared in the same class.
>
> •   The
>   name of a method must differ from the names of all other non-methods
>   declared in the same class. In addition, the signature (§3.6) of a
>   method must differ from the signatures of all other methods declared
>   in the same class, and two methods declared in the same class may not
>   have signatures that differ solely by ref and out.

Comment: Ok, so what do I do? Do I remove the indexer and replace both with non-property methods?

Answer (score -1):

Your second VB property is a 'parameterized property', not an indexer.
C# doesn't allow parameterized properties, but you can easily replace that property with 2 separate methods:

```
private double[] pAmount;
internal double[] Amount
{
    get
    {
        return pAmount;
    }
    set
    {
        pAmount = value;
    }
}

internal double getAmount(int idx)
{
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= pAmount.Length)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return pAmount[idx];
}
internal void setAmount(int idx, double value)
{
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= pAmount.Length)
    {
        return;
    }
    pAmount[idx] = value;
}
```

Comment: Ok I guess I'll go this way. The idea of the second method is to simply allow the user to pass in any index, and return zero if it's outside of the bounds. Is there some other way to do that?

Comment: This was the solution ultimately. It means you lose the nice API of having both an indexer and a settable property, but that is clearly the lesser of all evils. Thanks Dave!